# ProjectEuler 9: Why this is not working ( Java )?

Tags: java, break, goto

Problem says that only one triplet exists for which :
a+b+c=1000 and  a^2 + b^2 = c^2

I'm trying to find this triplet by simple brute force but it return every time a=1000, b=1000 and c=1000, and I can't understand why?

```
 public class Euler9
{

    static long Answer()
    {
        long a=1,b=1,c=1;

        outer:
        for( ; a<1000; ++a )
        {
            for( ; b<1000; ++b )
            {
                for( ; c<1000 ; ++c )
                {
                    if( (a+b+c == 1000) && (a*a+b*b == c*c) )
                    break outer;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(a+" + "+b+" + "+c+" = "+(a+b+c));
        return a*b*c;
    }

}
```

Comment: After you have increased `c` to 1000, it is never reset to 1, same with `b`. So you do not explore all possible combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loops need to initialize their index variables; your break needs to go to the code AFTER the nested loops.